# Issue with Try and Catch on Android

Tags: android, caching, try-catch, try-catch-finally, finally

As soon i execute the below code, the media is played for 60seconds and my app closes with an error "Unfortunately, YourAPP has stopped." . If i remove "bv.setImageResource(R.drawable.play);" on finally block, the app works perfectly.

what is the problem with bv.setImageResource(R.drawable.play) on finally block ??

This is my code

```
bv = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
private void mpsleep() {
    mp.start();
    Thread timer= new Thread(){
        public void run(){
            try{
                for (i =1;i<60;i++){
                    sleep(1000);//1 second pause
                }
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }finally{
                mp.pause();
                mp.seekTo(0);
                bv.setImageResource(R.drawable.play);
            }
        }
    };
    timer.start();
}
```

LogCat

```
03-06 11:03:39.743: V/MediaPlayer(31802): message received msg=4, ext1=0, ext2=0
03-06 11:03:39.743: V/MediaPlayer(31802): Received seek complete
03-06 11:03:39.743: V/MediaPlayer(31802): All seeks complete - return to regularly scheduled program
03-06 11:03:39.743: V/MediaPlayer(31802): callback application
03-06 11:03:39.743: V/MediaPlayer(31802): back from callback
03-06 11:03:39.743: E/MediaPlayer(31802): mOnSeekCompleteListener is null. Failed to send MEDIA_SEEK_COMPLETE message.
03-06 11:03:40.918: V/MediaPlayer(31802): isPlaying: 1
03-06 11:03:40.918: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(31802): isPlaying: 1
03-06 11:03:40.918: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(31802): pause
03-06 11:03:40.918: V/MediaPlayer(31802): pause
03-06 11:03:40.923: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(31802): seekTo: 0(msec)
03-06 11:03:40.923: V/MediaPlayer(31802): seekTo 0
03-06 11:03:40.923: V/MediaPlayer(31802): getDuration
03-06 11:03:40.923: V/MediaPlayer(31802): message received msg=4, ext1=0, ext2=0
03-06 11:03:40.923: W/dalvikvm(31802): threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40c541f8)
03-06 11:03:40.923: V/MediaPlayer(31802): Received seek complete
03-06 11:03:40.923: V/MediaPlayer(31802): All seeks complete - return to regularly scheduled program
03-06 11:03:40.923: V/MediaPlayer(31802): callback application
03-06 11:03:40.923: V/MediaPlayer(31802): back from callback
03-06 11:03:40.928: E/MediaPlayer(31802): mOnSeekCompleteListener is null. Failed to send MEDIA_SEEK_COMPLETE message.
03-06 11:03:40.953: E/AndroidRuntime(31802): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-20100
03-06 11:03:40.953: E/AndroidRuntime(31802): android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
03-06 11:03:40.953: E/AndroidRuntime(31802):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:4286)
03-06 11:03:40.953: E/AndroidRuntime(31802):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.requestLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:885)
03-06 11:03:40.953: E/AndroidRuntime(31802):    at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:12881)
03-06 11:03:40.953: E/AndroidRuntime(31802):    at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:12881)
03-06 11:03:40.953: E/AndroidRuntime(31802):    at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:12881)
03-06 11:03:40.953: E/AndroidRuntime(31802):    at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:12881)
03-06 11:03:40.953: E/AndroidRuntime(31802):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.requestLayout(RelativeLayout.java:268)
03-06 11:03:40.953: E/AndroidRuntime(31802):    at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:12881)
03-06 11:03:40.953: E/AndroidRuntime(31802):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.requestLayout(RelativeLayout.java:268)
03-06 11:03:40.953: E/AndroidRuntime(31802):    at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:12881)
03-06 11:03:40.953: E/AndroidRuntime(31802):    at android.widget.ImageView.setImageResource(ImageView.java:316)
03-06 11:03:40.953: E/AndroidRuntime(31802):    at com.hello.YourApp.MainActivity.stopsound(MainActivity.java:118)
03-06 11:03:40.953: E/AndroidRuntime(31802):    at com.hello.YourApp.MainActivity$6.run(MainActivity.java:143)
03-06 11:03:46.068: D/OpenGLRenderer(31802): Flushing caches (mode 0)
```

Comment: post the logcat and have you initialize the bv.

Comment: Post the logcat.. I guess you might be facing null pointer exception on bv

Comment: what is bv??(object of which control)

Comment: where are you initializing bv? Looks like bv might be null here

Comment: Remove your `bv.setImageResource(R.drawable.play);` from finally block and write it after the finally or out of the thread. Then try out

Comment: E/AndroidRuntime(31802): android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromW rongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.

Comment: you are calling `bv.setImageResource(R.drawable.play);` run this line on `UI thread`

Comment: i initialized bv Globally .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Exception message says it clearly:

> android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the
>   original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.

You cannot access UI elements from separate thread. Remove

```
setImageResource(R.drawable.play)
```

from `run()`.

If there's a little code (inside Activity class) that needs to be run on UI thread, you can use this method in Activity:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
  @override
  public void run(){
    //-- put code here--
  }
});
```

Comment: @SaiKiran you can wrap `setImageResource(R.drawable.play)` with sample code at the end of answer.

Answer (score 3):

Use UI thread as I have shown in following piece of code,

```
    bv = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
private void mpsleep() {
    mp.start();
    Thread timer= new Thread(){
        public void run(){
            try{
                for (i =1;i<60;i++){
                    sleep(1000);//5 second pause
                }
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }finally{
                mp.pause();
                mp.seekTo(0);
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
                bv.setImageResource(R.drawable.play);

        }
    });
            }
        }
    };
    timer.start();
}
```

**Explaination:**

-> You might have written `bv = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);` inside your `onCreate` or `onResume` method which runs on `Main thread(UI thread)`.

-> You have created a new thread `Thread timer= new Thread()` and trying to manipulate the component `bv`.but `bv` is bind to `Main Thread(UI thread)`.so you are having trouble.to resolve it,simply use `runOnUiThread(new Runnable)` method.

I hope it will be helpful !

Comment: I am glad to help you.Vote me up if it was helpful.I have edited answer by adding "Explaintion" to clear your doubt.

Answer (score 1):

Use handler to run your code 
bv.setImageResource(R.drawable.play);